# Table created with mysql but Ican't select from it using python

Tags: python, mysql

I've created  tables in mysql using python and i want to select
 from it to show data to user , but i found a problem in only one table.
This is the code :

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="aze123qsd",
database="GTFS"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM trips WHERE trip_id=11811;")
resultat=mycursor.fetchall()
print(resultat)
```

But when i use the same command on mysql it works

Comment: It works for tables other than trip in GTFS? Then I guess trip isn't in GTFS, Code is fine.

Comment: What does _"I can't select from it"_ mean? Why can't you select from it? What does it do, and how is that different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `;` in the execute statement

i.e. `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM trips WHERE trip_id=11811")`

Comment: Same problem even without the ;

Comment: dyou have more info about your db and the tables there?